# callback of function passes as variable

Tags: jquery, function, variables, callback

trying to pass a function name as a variable in order to call it in a function etc but can't figure out how to call it.

Any help welcome!

```
jQuery.fn.makeSlideShow = function(opts) { 

    opts = jQuery.extend({
        speed       :400,
        delay       :0,
        slideCLass  :'.slide',
        pager       :'#pager',
        next        :'.nextSlide',
        previous    :'.previousSlide',
        startSlide  :0,
        screenClick :false,
        callback:function(){return false;}
    },opts||{});

   //   callback the fullscreenImage function here?

};



$('#slideShow').makeSlideShow({
    callback : 'fullscreenImage'
});

function fullscreenImage(){
    alert('called!');
}
```

best, Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a string literal to your plugin. You need to pass the `function reference`

```
$('#slideShow').makeSlideShow({
    callback : fullscreenImage
});
```

Within your plugin code, you need to invoke that function. This can be done in several ways:

```
opts.callback();  // default call
opts.callback.call(scope, param1, param2, ...);  // invoke makeSlideShow with a specific context and arguments
opts.callback.apply(scope, [param1, param2, ...]); // invoke makeSlideShow with a specific context and arguments as array
```

Comment: ace - cheers andy! Just for future ref how would i pass params to the callback via makeSlideShow()?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably pass the identifier describing the function, rather than a string with its name. So switch this:

```
$('#slideShow').makeSlideShow({
    callback : 'fullscreenImage'
});
```

to this:

```
$('#slideShow').makeSlideShow({
    callback : fullscreenImage
});
```

Comment: Please comment downvotes so mistakes or left out details can be corrected. Downvotes for no obvious reason are just silly.

Answer (score 0):

If passing a string, you would need to know the scope where the function is located.

```
window[ opts.callback ]()
```

or

```
window[ opts.callback ].call( this )
```

These assume the function is global.

It would be better to require that a reference to the function is passed instead of a String.

```
$('#slideShow').makeSlideShow({
    callback : fullscreenImage
});

function fullscreenImage(){
    alert('called!');
}
```

Then you would do:

```
opts.callback()
```

or

```
opts.callback.call( this )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set 'callbeck' propety as follows:

```
$('#slideShow').makeSlideShow({
    callback : fullscreenImage
});
```

and than you can call it like this:

```
...
callback()
...
```